# Justification of using logarithm to simplify limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Sometimes one needs to find limits like

$$L=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)},$$

which usually are simplified to

$$L=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\ln f(x)\right),$$

where the new limit is found e.g. via l'Hôpital's rule or anything.

I always wondered, how is the step of exchanging $\exp$ and $\lim$ signs justified? Does it somehow follow from algebraic limit theorem?

Comment: It's only justified if $\lim \limits_{x\to a}(g(x)\ln f(x))\in \mathbb R$, in which case it's an immediate consequence of the continity of $\exp$.

Comment: @GitGud why wouldn't it work for $\mathbb C$? Isn't $\exp$ everywhere continuous?

Comment: My bad, assumed this was in the context of real analysis, but it doesn't change much. What I meant is that the limit must exist and be finite, otherwise you can't evaluate the exponential there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we have to prove is that if $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=A$ exists and is finite, and $f(x)$ is continuous at $A$, then $$\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=f\left(\lim_{x\to a} g(x)\right).\tag1$$

$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=A$ means:

$$\forall\varepsilon_x>0\;\exists \delta_x>0:\forall x\;(0<|x-a|<\delta_x\implies|g(x)-A|<\varepsilon_x).\tag2$$

Continuity of $f$ at $A$ means:

$$\forall \varepsilon_y>0\;\exists\delta_y>0:\forall y\;(0<|y-A|<\delta_y\implies|f(y)-f(A)|<\varepsilon_y).\tag3$$

Now we can take $y=g(x)$ and using arbitrariness of $\varepsilon_x$, we can take $\varepsilon_x=\delta_y$, then RHS of implication in $(2)$ becomes LHS of implication in $(3)$, so we have

$$|g(x)-A|<\delta_y\implies|f(g(x))-f(A)|<\varepsilon_y,$$

which with the conditions on $x$ from $(2)$ is equivalent to $(1)$, Q.E.D..